# How can I get the json file from firebase remote config in unity?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-remote-config

I looked through the threads with similar questions, but nothing worked for me. I'm trying to use `GetValue("my_value").StringValue`, but a blank line comes back to me.
FireBase is initialized, I get all values (double, string, bool) without problems. I can't get only json. what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Could you show how your database looks like and post a more complete code example?

Comment: "nothing worked for me" ---  "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"